# Extracting words and numbers from variable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to split a variable based on the type of characters.
I need this:

```
var = "word12345-54321" #No spaces to help out.
```

to turn into this:

```
var2 = "word"
var3 = "12345"
var4 = "54321"
```

I'm able to extract the word with regex, but I can't find a way to separate the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're already using a RegEx I'd suggest using a pattern like `(\D*)(\d*)-(\d*)` if the strings will always be in a `LETTERSNUMBERS-NUMBERS` format.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!